# Command line argument vectors in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

Do they exist? I have written a program that solves sudoku puzzles, and it takes 3 steps to run.

```
> prolog
> consult(sudoku).
> solve(puzzle).
```

I'm looking for a way to do something like

```
> prolog puzzle
```

and be done with it. Is there a way to do this IN Prolog? Or will I have to write some helper program in C or some other language to use like

```
> ./solve puzzle
```

Any help would be appreciated. Still new to Prolog, and having trouble finding good documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the Prolog system your are using. Most Prolog systems have a command line
start where one can provide an initial Prolog text to be consulted and an
initial Prolog goal to be run.

Here are some examples, I have combined the consult and run into one conjunctive goal:

[SWI-Prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%272.4%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/cmdline.html%27%29%29):

```
> swipl -t ['sudoku.p'],puzzle
```

[GNU Prolog](http://www.gprolog.org/manual/gprolog.html#htoc7):

```
> gprolog --entry-goal ['sudoku.p'],puzzle,halt
```

[Jekejeke Prolog](http://www.jekejeke.ch/idatab/doclet/prod/en/docs/05_run/10_docu/03_interface/08_headless/01_library.html):

```
> java -jar interpreter.jar -t ['sudoku.p'],puzzle
```

Best Regards

Comment: Thanks! Probably the best answer ever. Lol I like your project name Jekejeke.

Comment: Hey I'm using siwpl, and `swipl -t ['sudoku.p']` gets it to compile the module, but `puzzle` throws an error, because it doesn't get its argument, which is supposed to be a file name. Tried a couple other things like `...,solve(puzzle)` and `...,solve[puzzle]`. Couldn't get it going. Not a big deal if there's not a good way to pass args to functions in the command-line, but if there is, that would be sweeet.

Comment: Problem could be the consult. Maybe the extension is not .p but .pl. Or you need to give a longer path, and watchout for platform specific path separators. Then you can use ['path/soduku.pl'],solve(puzzle) all in one go without spaces. Spaces won't work since the conjunction wouldn't be recognized as one command line argument anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `-g` flag you can cause Prolog to execute a goal of your choice just before entering the top level. Default is a predicate which prints the welcome message. Moreover, you might like to use the `-t` flag that would replace the default goal prolog/0 by the one of your choice as an  interactive top-level.

See also [the manual](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%272.4%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/cmdline.html%27%29%29).

Answer (score 0):

use [optparse](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=optparse)

for example, if your program is:

```
main :-
    opt_arguments([], _, Args),
    write(Args).
```

and you run it like `./program 1 foo`
the program will write [1,foo]