# Get command line arguments in prolog

Tags: prolog, command-line-arguments, swi-prolog

Is there a standard function in prolog to get the arguments the compiled prolog executable was called with? `get_arguments/0` or something like that? If there is no standard, is there at least a way to do that in swi-prolog?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10365340/command-line-argument-vectors-in-prolog?rq=1

Comment: @RandyHoward that does not work with compiled prolog programs though

Comment: try `current_prolog_flag(argv, Argv), append(_, [--|Args], Argv), `. as seen here: http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section(2,'2.10',swi('/doc/Manual/compilation.html'))